# Filter with count distinct from other table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have two tables as follow:
[image: 2 tables with a relation one to many]
I am trying to find every wire that haves at least 2 type of pins also there can be lots of pins of the same type assigned to 1 wire.
My logic in sql would be something like:

```
select * from wire x where (select count(*) from pin y where x.id = y.wireId) = 2;
```

I've already tried a couple of things the last one was:

```
DetachedCriteria cav = criteriaQuery.createCriteria("pins");   
cav.setProjection(Projections.countDistinct("type")).setResultTransformer(Criteria.ROOT_ENTITY);
criteriaQuery.add(Subqueries.eq(Integer.parseInt(value), cav));
```

Which resulted in a Null pointer exception in getTypedValues inside hibernate.

Any help would be appreciated even if it is just more resources to learn hibernate better

Comment: Did you try to run your SQL in any SQL work bench?

Comment: You don't always have to use a `CriteriaQuery` although it might be cleaner and safer to do so.  Have you tried writing HQL for this query?

Comment: yes in oracle sql developer it seems to return what i'm looking for even if it isn't the fastest query. but my question it's about the criteria

Comment: It's an application that was already developed with the DetachedCriteria on mind, so if it is possible I would rather not change too much. So I still didn't try doing the hql way (which would probably  be easier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be the best answer but for now I solved it by doing something like this:

```
    DetachedCriteria a = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Pin.class);
    String groupBy = "wireId having count(DISTINCT type) >=2";
    String[] alias = new String[1];
    alias[0] = "wireId ";
    Type[] types = new Type[1];
    types[0] = Hibernate.STRING;

    a.setProjection(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("wireId", groupBy, alias, types));
    criteriaQuery.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("wireId", a));
```